# Facebook notifications sent to personal messenger account

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

This is a general question, would love some feedback from those of you that have some experience with the facebook API, and other related tech.

I would like to know if this is even possible, and perhaps some pointers on how it might be achieved..

Looking into building a messenger bot that transmits your notifications on facebook to your personal messenger account.

The purpose being that you would not have to visit the facebook app or webpage to be up to date on your notifications. Some (such as myself) prefer not to use facebook at all, but i need to be up to date on events, etc.

Facebook does however give you the opportunity to get notifications via email or sms, but i would rather have it sent to messenger.

Any feedback at all would be great, Thanks!

Comment: No that is not possible. There is no API to read notifications. And there is no API to send message to messenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could poll the notifications API on a regular basis https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications/.

In regards to sending the message to the user, bots typically have a 24 hour window where they're allowed to interact with the user, so you could set it up to respond to a command like "What are my events?" returns the latest event notifications.

But a better solution would be the [subscription messaging that is in beta](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy/policy-overview#subscription_messaging). Subscription messaging is designed for long running bots, like a news service that gives you a news update every morning. Subscription messaging combined with [account linking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/account-linking) would allow you to create a bot that asks for you to login to your Facebook account on first contact, and then push updates to it whenever you like.

Comment: appreciate the answer.Will research this further.